# Android project - where I can save video?

Tags: android, video

I create Android project - application ...

But where I can save the video and after that use it in application?

I'll play the video in my app.

Comment: Do you want to bundle a video file with your apk, or to download it dynamically and store on the device?

Comment: You can create a folder like raw inside of res folder and then you can access it threw R.raw.video_name

Answer (score 0):

To create a directory you can use the following code:

```
File dir = new File("path/to/your/directory");
try{
if(dir.mkdir()) {
    System.out.println("Directory created");
 } else {
 System.out.println("Directory is not created");
}
   catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And Use This to play video by giving your directory path

```
   videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

   Uri video =              Uri.parse("http://www.servername.com/projects/projectname/videos/1361439400.mp4"   );
  videoView.setVideoURI(video);
   videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override       
   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
   mp.setLooping(true);
   videoView.start();
    }
  });
```